# Cookies with Fetch polyfill in Jest

Tags: javascript, cookies, jestjs, fetch-api, e2e-testing

I'm setting up e2e tests in jest, and I'd like to have fetch send my cookies when I call it like:

```
const userinfo = await fetch('/api/auth/me')
```

I've set up my jest config with

```
testEnvironmentOptions: {
  url: 'http://localhost:5544/'
},
```

and added `import 'whatwg-fetch'` to my jest.setup.js file, which is great it gets me to the point where my fetch requests are working on relative paths. However, I cannot for the life of me get fetch to send along my auth cookie.

I've added my cookie to the document like so

```
  Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'cookie', {
    writable: true,
    value: 'auth=...',
  });
```

I've tried setting my fetch `credentials` property to `include` and `same-origin` with no luck. I read through the CORS guide, but that's all about how to get the browser to set the cookie - in my case I've already set the cookie myself. On my server the request always comes through with no cookie attached. I'm stumped, has anyone else solved this issue before?

UPDATE:
I have tried more things without success:

1. adding domain and path to the cookie

```
  Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'cookie', {
    writable: true,
    value: 'auth=...;domain=localhost:5544;path=/',
  });
```

2. adding 'same-origin' mode to verify that the request is the same origin (it is, the request goes through without error)

```
const userinfo = await fetch('/api/auth/me', {credentials: "same-origin", mode: 'same-origin'});
```

3. checking the headers on the incoming request on the server side:

```
{
  referer: 'http://localhost:5544/',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (darwin) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/20.0.3',
  'accept-language': 'en',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  host: 'localhost:5544',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}
```

None of these things has helped, the request still goes through without attaching the cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!! Took me a while of hunting down what was happening, but basically jsdom has its own `cookie` [implementation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/a39e0ec4ce9a8806692d986a7ed0cd565ec7498a/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js#L851), and so calling `Object.defineProperty` was overriding the implementation in jsdom. AWESOME. All you have to do is set

```js
document.cookie = 'auth=...'
```

and you're good to go. I also discovered that fetch defaults to `{credentials: 'same-origin'}` so my calls can just be:

```js
await fetch(`/api/auth/me`)
```

and everything is gold.